# Wordpress Database connection limit

Tags: php, wordpress, azure

I have installed WordPress at Azure, and my database is limited to four connections at maximum.

1. For blog and website pages, will all the new pages and content be pulled from the database every time the user will visit the website?   Or is it HTML generated pages?
2. Any way to avoid database dependency that HTML pages are generated.

Answer (score 0):

First your questions:

1. if you won't use cache, yes.
2. using wordpress cache plugins.

There are some things you can do:

1. Install a mysql in a Virtual Machine or upgrade your clear db (microsoft partner that offers mysql in azure) to a special version.
2. Use wordpress cache plugins, so it will create a in memory version of your posts posts and avoid a DB hit every time.